# Python variable should not change, but it changed?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a strange behavior with a variable in the following code.

Why is the output of w3 at the end the same as w2? Its never been changed in the code, but in the end it has the same value as w2?

```
import numpy as np

inpt = np.array([[1]])

w1 = np.random.random((1,1))
w2 = np.random.random((1,1))

w3 = w2

print("First w3: ", w3)

n1 = np.dot(inpt, w1)
n2 = np.dot(n1, w2)

delta = 1 - n2

n1_d = np.dot(delta, w2.T)

w2 += np.dot(n1.T, delta)
w1 += np.dot(inpt.T, n1_d)

print("Second w3: ", w3)

print("Value of w2: ", w2)
```

> First w3:  [[ 0.98377014]]
>
> Second w3:  [[ 1.01105407]]
>
> Value of w2:  [[ 1.01105407]]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not a python expert so I might be wrong. Is it because w3 is just a reference to w2? So when you change w3, w2 reference's w3's new value. It changes after this line `w2 += np.dot(n1.T, delta)`

Comment: Use `w3 = np.copy(w2)`

Comment: It looks like you're not clear on how Python variables and assignment work. Here's a [handy guide](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: There's also some good, relevant info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list). That question is about plain Python lists, but much of the info is applicable to any mutable object in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`w3` is just a reference to `w2` so it will reflect the change in `w2` when you update `w2`